# How can I measure the memory used by a Boost graph?

Tags: c++, memory, boost, boost-graph

I have a graph defined as follow (using boost):

```
struct NodeData{ /*...*/ };
struct EdgeData{ /*...*/ };
typedef adjacency_list<setS, setS, undirectedS, NodeData, EdgeData> MyGraph;
MyGraph G;
```

This graph is updated iteratively (by adding/deleting some edges/vertices). At each iteration, I want to evaluate the memory space occupied by this graph G. How can I do that ? and does it make sense if I compute V = "the size of NodeData" and E = "the size of EdgeData" and at each iteration the memory used by the graph will be proportional to: nbr_vertices * V + nbr_edges * E ?

Comment: What does this question have to do with time complexity?

Comment: @RobKennedy tag error, I removed it

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Heap State Reporting functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc28wkas%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Well, I can not use visual c++, and I want only the memory used by the graph, not other objects (i.e. at each iteration I also manipulate other things than my graph). So this not seems the good function for what I've asked.

Comment: What if I compute V = "the size of NodeData" and E = "the size of EdgeData" and at each iteration the memory used by the graph will be proportional to: nbr_vertices * V + nbr_edges * E ?